# Not able to install software on macOS using installer

Tags: macos-sierra

I just bought a new MacBook Pro 2016 Edition about 2 weeks ago.
I installed a bunch of applications and software so far by copying them into Applications Folder as well as by following installer wizard.

Now today I tried to install Wireshark using installer wizard. I tried to install teamviewer too later today which also uses installer wizard. And both give me the same error.[image: Installer Encountered an Error that caused installer to fail.]

I really need to resolve this because I need TeamViewer soon and I'm not finding anyone else facing this issue online anywhere.

Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked everywhere. Didn't find a viable solution. But then reinstalled the OS. Which didn't affect any of my data or installed application. I got the whole Operating System the same way I left it. But resolved the issue I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered such an error before,to solve it dont copy the pakage to your app folder, but instead open it with admin powers and that should fix the issue.
If you have purchased this software then you can call the tech support, else dont call them it can put you in danger for installing pirated software.

Comment: I went to the mounted partition by TeamViewer and tried this command.
```sudo installer -pkg /path/to/package.pkg -target /```
But didn't help. It is also giving me the same error message in terminal as the UI above.